# PHP submitting wildcard characters in a string

Tags: php, mysql, string, wildcard

I have a system where codes get inserted into a database, for example AREF0OGS would be a code.

The problem I am having is that when the codes are distributed, the difference between 0 and O is illegible, so I need a way that the current system can treat an 0 and O  the same (as long as it's in the same part of the string).

Here is what I have:

```
$code = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['code']);  
$userid = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['userid']); 

$resultcode = mysql_query('select * from xxxxxx where code = "'. $code .'"' ) or die(mysql_error());
```

Is there a way I can treat 0's and O's the same? In PHP or MySQL?

Thanks

Comment: `'select * from xxxxxx where code LIKE "'. str_replace(array('0','O'), '_', $code) .'"'`

Comment: Don't use Mysql_* friend as they're out of date now. Use PDO or Mysqli instead. The above solution should work for you :)

Comment: @MarkBaker wouldn't it match AREFAAGS and AREFIOGS and AREF(any-two-letters)GS ? I dont think that is what they intended as a result.

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet is before you do your query you could replace one with the other.  This could be done in either MySQL

```
select * from table where code=replace($code, 'O', '0')
```

Or in PHP

```
$code = str_replace('O', '0', $code);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just always replace O letter with 0 digit (or the other way).

```
$code = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['code']);   $code =
str_replace('0', '0', $code); $userid =
mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['userid']); 

$resultcode = mysql_query('select * from xxxxxx where code = "'. $code .'"' ) or die(mysql_error());
```